# Ansible: convert csv data into a directory

Tags: csv, ansible, ansible-filter

I am trying to figure out how to do a simple csv interpolation in Ansible. I tried all kinds of filters and loops but I can't figure out how to make this work.

I have: A llst of csv text lines with the first item of the list holding the field names.

I want: A list of hashes of Field name -> Value for each of the value lines.

So can someone help?

Thanks,

Oren

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. `I tried all kinds of filters and loops` => please show us what you have done and the problems you are facing. If you don't know how to present that, have a look at [creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the help section.

Comment: @Oren: To answer your question: "Is there a similar module that does the same for an array rather than a file ( or some way to pipe the array into the read_csv module)?" I'm not aware of such a module. Piping an array to read_csv would mean to write the array to a file and read it.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"**Convert** a list of csv text lines with the first item of the list holding the field names **to** a list of hashes of Field name -> Value for each of the value lines"*.

A: Module [read_csv](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/read_csv_module.html#read-csv-read-a-csv-file) does exactly what you're looking for. For example

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - read_csv:
        path: data.csv
      register: vms
    - debug:
        var: vms.list
```

with the data

```
$ cat data.csv
hostname,partition,ip
hostname1,/dev/sda1,10.1.0.21
hostname2,/dev/sda1,10.1.0.22
hostname3,/dev/sda1,10.1.0.23
```

gives

```
   "vms.list": [
        {
            "hostname": "hostname1", 
            "ip": "10.1.0.21", 
            "partition": "/dev/sda1"
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "hostname2", 
            "ip": "10.1.0.22", 
            "partition": "/dev/sda1"
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "hostname3", 
            "ip": "10.1.0.23", 
            "partition": "/dev/sda1"
        }
    ]
```

> Q: *"Does the same for an array rather than a file."*

A: The play below gives the same result

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_array:
      - [hostname, partition, ip]
      - [hostname1, /dev/sda1, 10.1.0.21]
      - [hostname2, /dev/sda2, 10.1.0.22]
      - [hostname3, /dev/sda3, 10.1.0.23]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        keys_list: "{{ my_array.0 }}"
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_list|default([]) + [dict(keys_list|zip(item))] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_array[1:] }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

See [zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters).